# Using Google Drive API in Python Flask web app to upload files in background without user OAuth

Tags: python, flask, google-drive-api, google-oauth

I'm hosting a Flask Web App on GCP and I want to periodically archive a file to my Google Drive (the reason for this is because I like how multiple users can access/edit GDrive from anywhere easily cross-platform using GDrive Desktop without having to login to cloud platforms).

The issue is that with the method I've tried, the app asks the user to login via OAuth to set up the API authentication. I want this process to happen in the background without the user having to login to Google. I want to OAuth the application, not the user.

This is the code that I use to upload files currently (it works, I just have that OAuth issue).

```
import io
import json
from httplib2 import Http
from apiclient.discovery import build
from oauth2client import file, client, tools
from apiclient.http import MediaIoBaseUpload

SCOPES = 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.file'
store = file.Storage('credentials.json')
creds = store.get()
if not creds or creds.invalid:
    flow = client.flow_from_clientsecrets('client_secrets.json', SCOPES)
    creds = tools.run_flow(flow, store)
drive_service = build('drive', 'v3', http=creds.authorize(Http()))

def upload__drive(name,input_dict):
    file_metadata = {
    'name': name + '.json',
    'parents': ['FOLDER_ID'],
    'mimeType': 'text/json',
    }

    media = MediaIoBaseUpload(io.BytesIO(json.dumps(input_dict).encode('utf-8')), 
                            mimetype='text/json')
    file = drive_service.files().create(body=file_metadata, media_body=media, fields='id').execute()
```

I've seen another method, of doing a POST request using a URL with body? I'm not overly familiar with how GET/POST requests work though and against couldn't get it to work without OAuth-ing the user.

It also has the issue of being unable to write to 'credentials.json' whilst on GCP due to the lack of hard drive in a serverless app, I can get around this with Google Bucket storage if I find a method that works for me.

Thanks in advance,

Watch & Shoot

Comment: If you want them uploading to your drive account then you should be using a service account

Comment: Yeah I have a service account setup, and all the OAuth and APIs required. Hang on... when I'm being prompted to sign in when the app boots up, is that a one off event? Just for me as the service account owner? I assumed that everyone who accessed the app had to log in with google also..... that would explain a few things! I'll redeploy and test from another PC.

Comment: If you are prompting the user then you are not using a service account